# EC2 SSH Prompting for Password

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I spawned an instance with the `Parallels Plesk with PowerPanel`, running on CentOS, I attempted to ssh into it. For some reason, it's prompting for a password. I'm telling it where the keyfile is, and it's still not working. Help?

```
ssh -v -i .ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@ec2-184-73-97-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-184-73-97-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com [184.73.97.136] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 4c:6b:f7:1d:50:d9:dc:a1:bd:4a:d2:7c:7d:bd:9f:01
debug1: Host 'ec2-184-73-97-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/ian/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ec2-user@ec2-184-73-97-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com's password:
```

Comment: Your SSH client offered the key and the server rejected it. Check that you're using the right keyfile, it matches the key in AWS, you configured the instance to use that key, and that the AMI installs SSH keys.

Comment: @mgorven What do you mean by "check that the AMI installs SSH keys"? Do some AMIs do that while others do not? Is there a list of which ones install keys on startup?

Comment: @culix Custom built AMI's might not accept keyfiles from AWS.

Comment: @IanCarroll But do Amazon-supplied AMIs definitely copy down keyfiles from AWS? If so do you have a reference for that? I can't seem to find it explicitly mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @IanCarroll As for your question, I agree with mgorven; the server is asking for a password because keyfile authentication has failed. 1. Does your current user own the key file? `sudo chown {currentusername} {filename.pem}`. 2. Have you successfully ssh-ed into this machine before? 3. can you verify that .ssh/id_rsa is the correct key to connect to this server? (do you have other keys?)

Comment: @culix I don't have a citation but it would be rather dumb to not, wouldn't it? Why hard code a key into an image your clients need to use?

Comment: @culix I did end up fixing it by regenerating my keys and the server on AWS.